# Take the subsets of a data.frame with the same feature and select a single row from each subset

Tags: r, random

Suppose I have a matrix in R as follows:

```
ID Value
1 10
2 5
2 8
3 15
4 7
4 9
...
```

What I need is a random sample where every element is represented once and only once.

That means that ID 1 will be chosen, one of the two rows with ID 2, ID 3 will be chosen, one of the two rows with ID 4, etc...

There can be more than two duplicates.

I'm trying to figure out the most R-esque way to do this without subsetting and sampling the subsets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tapply` across the `rownames` and grab a `sample` of `1` in each `ID` group:

```
dat[tapply(rownames(dat),dat$ID,FUN=sample,1),]

#  ID Value
#1  1    10
#3  2     8
#4  3    15
#6  4     9
```

If your data is truly a `matrix` and not a `data.frame`, you can work around this too, with:

```
dat[tapply(as.character(seq(nrow(dat))),dat$ID,FUN=sample,1),]
```

Don't be tempted to remove the `as.character`, as `sample` will give unintended results when there is only one value passed to it. E.g.

```
replicate(10, sample(4,1) )
#[1] 1 1 4 2 1 2 2 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with dplyr like so:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% sample_n(1)
```

Comment: You can also look at dplyr's function `sample_frac()` to sample fractions of each grouping variable, for example 10% of the rows.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is reorder the rows randomly and then remove duplicates in that order.

```
df <- read.table(text="ID Value
1 10
2 5
2 8
3 15
4 7
4 9", header=TRUE)

df2 <- df[sample(nrow(df)), ]
df2[!duplicated(df2$ID), ]
```