# Random selection based on a variable in a R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with 1000 columns. It is a dataset of animals from different breeds. However I have more animals from some breeds. So what I want to do is to select a random sample of those breeds with more animals and make all breeds with the same number of observations.
In details: I have 400 Holstein animals, 300 Jersey, 100 Hereford and 150 Nelore and 50 Canchim. What I want to do is to randomly select 50 animals from each breed. So I would have a total of 250 animals at the end. I know how to randomly select using runif, however I am not sure how I can apply that in my case.
My data looks like:

```
Breed   ID    Trait1    Trait2  Trait3
Holstein    1       11     22     44
Jersey      2       22     33     55
Nelore      3       33     44     66
Nelore      4       44     55     77
Canchim     5       55     66     88
```

I have tried:

```
Data = data[!!ave(seq_along(data$Breed), unique(data$Breed), FUN=function(x) sample(x, 50) == x),]
```

However, it does not work and I am not allowed to install the package dplyr in the server that I am using.
Thank in advance.

Comment: you can `split` your data by breed, ie `split(dat, dat$Breed)`, that should give a list of data.frames.  So, `lapply` a sampling procedure to that list and bind back together, `do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dat, dat$Breed), function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), 50),]))`.  not tested but hopefully would work

Comment: I just thought of a trickier way that doesn't require splitting the data.  You can order by Breed, `dat <- dat[order(dat$Breed),]`.  Then, since `match` finds the first match, you can find the starting index of each unique breed, `inds <- c(match(unique(dat$Breed), dat$Breed),nrow(dat))`.  Now, use `mapply` to sample 50 indices between each species, `res <- c(mapply(function(a,b) sample(a:b, 50), head(inds,-1), tail(inds,-1)))`.  So, your result would be `dat[res,]`.

Comment: This is essentially the same as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28535518/496803 - e.g. `iris[unlist(tapply(1:nrow(iris), iris$Species, sample, size=2)),]`

Comment: @thelatemail nice one, I guess it is just a wrapper for the `lapply(split` method.  Gonna start using that a lot more.

Comment: @bunk - essentially, yep. If you can avoid needing to work with large objects, and deal with indexes which are then applied to a large object once, you will end up with efficient code.

Comment: thanks @thelatemail. That worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` your animals data frame on the breed, and then apply a custom function to each chunk which will randomly extract 50 rows:

```
animals.split <- split(animals, animals$Breed)
animals.list <- lapply(animals.split, function(x) {
                   y <- x[sample(nrow(x), 50), ]
                   return(y)
                }
result <- unsplit(animals.list, f = animals$Breed)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I am getting an error when I do that. Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) :
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed. Do you know why is that?

Comment: Try using `unsplit`.  I am on a cell phone right now.